# Android :Button drawable Top

Tags: android, button, icons, drawable

I want to create metro UI, so I did like in the picture But the problem is the position of the icons, they are in the top of the button, and I don't think it's aesthetic interface. I inserted the icons in the drawable Top in the button. Well how can make the a little bit in the middle.

[image]

Comment: You can set the toppadding to adjust the drawable top. And use android:drawablePadding to mention the padding between the text and the icon. Its better to use a imageview and a textview within a vertical linear layout or a relative layout.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the android:paddingTop and android:paddingBottom eqaully. Just don't copy and paste 10dp as the value of the padding. Value depends on the size of your button. Refer to below:

```
             <Button
                android:id="@+id/find_teacher"
                style="@style/page_button"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_search_light"
                android:text="@string/find_teacher" 
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"/>
```

**This is the output:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I can remember 2 options:

- top padding
- gravity

You might wan't to check the layout [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html)